# Making a "fluid grid" with divs & css/bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: CSS div]

Is it possible to create something like this with either raw css or bootstrap? I want to have it set up where each button is a fixed size and is written in a list format where I don't have to define a specific row or column length. Ex:

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

But like I said, each box item needs to be a square with an exact side length. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please take a look at [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp) in css:

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid orange 3px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```